# How to import BigIntegerWritable in Reducer?

Tags: java, hadoop, biginteger

I'm writting a reducer and the value for each key could be very large number (larger than the range of `long` value). I planned to use `BigInteger` as the value's type and I noticed there's a class [BigIntegerWritable](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/BigIntegerWritable.html) defined in pig. However, I use the library `pig-0.11.0.jar` or `pig-0.11.0-withouthadoop.jar` to compile. It couldn't find the `BigIntegerWritable`.

Here's the command I use to compile:

`javac -classpath /var/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/var/pig/pig-0.11.0.jar wordcount.java wordcountReducer.java wordcountMapper.java`

Here's the error message:

```
wordcountReducer.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.BigIntegerWritable;
                                ^
symbol:   class BigIntegerWritable
location: package org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop
wordcountReducer.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
implements Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, BigIntegerWritable> {
                                           ^
symbol: class BigIntegerWritable
wordcountReducer.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
OutputCollector<Text, BigIntegerWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                        ^
symbol:   class BigIntegerWritable
location: class wordcountReducer
wordcountReducer.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
output.collect(key, new BigIntegerWritable(wordNumber));
                        ^
symbol:   class BigIntegerWritable
location: class wordcountReducer
4 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain `BigIntegerWritable` became a thing in Pig 0.12 as seen [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/BigIntegerWritable.html). So you would need that version. Even still, I don't think it is really appropriate to include Pig here just to get a class to help your reducer.

I think you are better off writing your own `BigIntegerWritable`. It wouldn't be too hard since it already has methods to go to and from `byte[]`. Just use `IntWritable` as a model.